# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[{2n \choose n+1} \frac1{2n\cdot2^{2n}}\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{\ln(1-x)} dx\right]= \int_0^1 \frac{x-x^2}{2(1+x)\ln x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

The question is to prove$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[{2n \choose n+1} \frac1{2n\cdot2^{2n}}\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{\ln(1-x)}\mathbb dx\right]
= \frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{x-x^2}{(1+x)\ln x}\mathbb dx\\
$$
This is a part of the steps to prove that the LHS equals to $\ln{\frac{\sqrt\pi}2}$. However, I cannot prove the above equation.

I can see that using calculations the above equation is indeed true.

I also see that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[{2n \choose n+1} \frac1{2n\cdot2^{2n}}\frac{x^n}{\ln(1-x)}\right]
\ne \frac12 \frac{x-x^2}{(1+x)\ln x}\\
$$

So the integrands are not equal, but the definite integrals become equal somehow.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{n}\binom{2n}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n} = C_n$ is the $n$th Catalan number. It may consequently help to substitute the generating function for Catalan numbers into the LHS.

Comment: The result is correct, see a proof below in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**OP seems to have done some mistake, the acclaimed result is correct**

Let us use $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty {2k \choose k} \left(\frac{z}{4}\right)^k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}}-1,\quad |z|<1.$$
Integrating it w.r.t.z from $z=0$ to $z=x$ and simplifying, we get
$$F(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2k)!}{k!(k+1)!}\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)^{k}= \frac{2-2\sqrt{1-x}-x}{x}$$
Let $S$ be the required sum in here as
$$
S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[{2n \choose n+1} \frac1{2n\cdot2^{2n}}\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{\ln(1-x)}\mathbb dx\right]$$

$$S=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{F(x)}{2\ln(1-x)}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2-x-2\sqrt{1-x}}{2x\ln (1-x)} dx. $$
Next use $x\to 1-x$, to get
$$S=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1+x-2\sqrt{x}}{2(1-x)\ln x}dx=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-\sqrt{x})^2}{2(1-x)\ln x}dx=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-\sqrt{x})}{2(1+\sqrt{x})\ln x}dx.$$
Finally, take $x=z^2 \implies dx=2 z dz$ to get
$$S=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{z(1-z)dz}{2(1+z)\ln z}dz$$